mongoose .populate() is returning an empty array
I know this question has been asked a lot but I cant find a single solution that fixes my problem.
populated comments in the post return an empty array, although the comment does exist with the corresponding post id.
I Have posts with reference to the comments like so:
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    status: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

and this is how i try to populate the comments:
const posts = await Post.find()
            .populate('author', 'username profileImage')
            .populate('comments');

this is how my comment schema looks:
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

Thank you for any help!
I tried linking the comments and posts, having comments with a post property that links to the post and vice versa.

Your Post documents need to contain the ObjectId of each Comment document you want to reference within the Post.comments array. With mongoose you need to manually push each Comments ObjectId into that array.
